# Practical estimate for a capacitor discharge through a resistor and an LED in series

Tags: capacitor, discharge

This question was [asked before](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/47126/discharging-a-capacitor-through-a-resistor-and-an-led-in-series), but I am struggling with the same question and I can't figure out "how to deal with it in the real world" as someone put it at the time.

Olin's approximation is the first idea I came up with: assume the LED is a voltage source, assume the capacitor initially charges up to 5V - Vled_drop, and assume a simple RC discharge. However simulating the circuit seems to show that the approximation is nowhere close to being valid. With this circuit:
[image: Circuit]

If I assume a simple RC discharge model the simulator gives

```
RC = - 3s / Ln(V(3s) / (5V - Vs)) = 4.5
```

after 3s, when the calculated value would be

```
RC = 1.8mF * 1k = 1.8
```

(the simulator uses Vs = 1.64V for a red LED).

[image: t = 0s]  [image: t = 3s]

In other terms the capacitor discharges much slower than the RC=1.8 would indicate.
Is there any better way to predict what will roughly happen without a simulator, or without solving the actual differential equations?

Franck

Comment: Why would anyone not use a simulator?

Comment: I tried that yesterday to tune a MosFET based astable multivibrator, and my conclusion is that when you don't understand the basics that doesn't really get you anywhere :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first RC formula is not right. You need to consider Vf=1.64V of the LED as an offset for the input voltages. This is the correct formula:

RC = -t/ln((Vt-Vf)/(V0-Vf)) = -3/ln((2-1.64)/(3.87-1.64)) = 1.65 Seconds

Comment: That was my mistake indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRwYCl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The test circuit.*

I haven't time to try to figure out your equations which seem to contain both variables and SI unit symbols (which makes it very difficult to read). I offer the following comments:

- Assume that the LED V<sub>f</sub> = 2 V.
- When SW1 is closed C1 will charge up to about 2/3 of the way from V<sub>D1</sub> to 5 V due to the R1 / R2 ratio - so about 4 V.
- During discharge you can assume that  V<sub>f</sub> will remain fairly constant although it will decrease with current.
- Your RC discharge is now calculated from 4 V to 2 V. So your RC time constant is τ = R<sub>2</sub>C<sub>1</sub> = 1.8 s so you should see a discharge of 63% from 4 V to 2 V (1.26 V) in 1.8 s.

Try that out and see if it clarifies anything.

Comment: Indeed, I had missed that the discharge is down to Vd, not to 0... thanks!